# Too much padding on my site in iOS

Tags: css, ios

This is my website I made for a friend and it looks great however when viewing it on iOS (iPhone & iPad) it had extra padding on the right. I never even told it to have padding at all so I'm not even sure what snipit of CSS I should provide. I've looked with firebug but can't find anything.

This is what it looks like on my iPhone
[image]

Can anyone tell me why my padding to the right is so much?

Is there also a good reason for why the link WINERY is on the second line? There is well enough space for it as seen on android and desktop browsers but for some reason it's on the second line in iOS.

```css
#access {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does your meta initial-scale/ initial width tag look like? For mobile devices, you shouldn't necessarily be setting a static width.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I just have "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />" in my <head> tag. I tried at one point to make my website fluid, with a responsive design but with issues with IE I gave up and I haven't had a big problem with using static size so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make the width larger? I have found on my designs that sometimes the width is rendered just slightly different on iOS and I've solved this in many cases by slightly expanding the width.

Also, if you're using a list to display that nav-menu I have found that reducing the padding or margin (if any) on `<li>` elements by a few pixels can help a problem.

Comment: Which width are you talking about? The width of any wrappers I have for the site? And I did try to decrease the padding and margins but that didn't do anything for my navigation.

Comment: The width of the container containing the nav-menu, I assumed this was `#access` you showed above... See if making it larger than 600px helps any.